# std::array with unspecialized template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is it possible to pass somehow unspecialized template class as a template parameter to std::array? Something similar to that:

```
template <class T>
class Field{
};

std::array<Field> a;
```

Or I have to define some BaseField, and sublass it as a IntField, StringField, FloatField.... ?

Comment: No, `Field` isn't a type, `Field<int>` and `Field<float>` are types.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a template that takes a template as a parameter (aka, a template template parameter). The template has to be written specifically to take a template as a parameter to allow it though, and `std::array` isn't specified to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can get pretty close with C++11, using an alias template:

```
template <typename T>
struct Field {}; 

template <typename T>
using FieldArray5 = std::array<Field<T>,5>;

int main() {

  FieldArray5<int> a0;

}
```

But bear in mind that `std::array` needs a template argument for the size too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an `std::array` to hold different types, it can only be done through polymorphism. You can also use `boost::any` that hides that polymorphism from you but still implements it.